# How to show JSON array data by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a ajax returning json array data like this,

```
[{
    "UserName": "John",
    "Total": "45",
    "Correct(%)": "71.1111",
    "Incorrect(%)": "28.8889"
}, {
    "UserName": "KKK",
    "Total": "42",
    "Correct(%)": "47.6190",
    "Incorrect(%)": "52.3810"
}, {
    "UserName": "AAA",
    "Total": "54",
    "Correct(%)": "81.4815",
    "Incorrect(%)": "18.5185"
}, {
    "UserName": "BBB",
    "Total": "39",
    "Correct(%)": "58.9744",
    "Incorrect(%)": "41.0256"
}]
```

I want to show that data by using javascript like this,

> UserName: John    Total: 45       Correct(%): 71.1111
>   Incorrect(%): 28.8889
>
> UserName: KKK    Total: 42       Correct(%): 47.6190
>   Incorrect(%): 52.3810
>
> UserName: AAA     Total: 54       Correct(%): 81.4815
>   Incorrect(%): 18.5185
>
> UserName: BBB       Total: 39       Correct(%): 58.9744
>   Incorrect(%): 41.0256

So, I try like this,

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'some.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {dept:d},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("success");
                    var temp = "";
                    if(data && data!="") {
                        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                            $.each(data,function(k,v){
                                $.each(v,function(k,s){
                                    temp +=k+': <b>'+s+'</b> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp';
                                });
                                temp +="<br/><br/>";
                                console.log(temp);
                            });
                        }

                        document.getElementById('user').innerHTML= temp;
                    }
});
```

But, I got five line for each user. I was wrong while looping. So, how can I do this?

Comment: try removing the `for loop`

Comment: Thank you so much. Now, Its ok.

Comment: @roullie make it as answer

Comment: @roullie make your comment to answer please.

Comment: @NightMare comment made to answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `for` loop.

```
 //for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    $.each(data,function(k,v){
        $.each(v,function(k,s){
           temp +=k+': <b>'+s+'</b> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp';
        });
        temp +="<br/><br/>";
        console.log(temp);
    });
 //}
```

Comment: @NightMare no problem. glad i could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'some.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {dept:d},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
        var temp = '';
        if(data && data != "") {
            var temp = '<ul>';
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                temp += '<li>UserName: ' + data[i]['UserName'] + '&nbsp;Total: ' + data[i]['Total'] + '&nbsp;Correct(%): ' + data[i]['Correct(%)'] + '&nbsp;Incorrect(%): ' + data[i]['Incorrect(%)'] + '</li>';
            }
            temp += '</ul>';

            document.getElementById('user').innerHTML = temp;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Its the different way.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use 1 $.each loop, otherwise you are looping through all the data muliple times.